# Openshift- application error while starting

Tags: java, openshift

I am trying to deploy springboot application with mysql as database on openshift platform. I have pulled the database image and its running. But when i pulled the spring application, it is deployed and connecting to database. But, still i am not able to hit the endpoint and when i check the pods i am getting **Crashloopback** error.

Can anyone help me to get it resolve.

> > NAME                          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
> >
> > mysql-3-deploy                0/1     Completed          0          43m
> >
> > mysql-3-p2rb6                 1/1     Running            0          43m
> >
> > partydetailswithdb-1-deploy   0/1     Completed          0          46m
> >
> > partydetailswithdb-2-cs8jp    0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   12         41m
> >
> > partydetailswithdb-2-deploy   0/1     Completed          0          41m
> >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:09.519  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.openbanking.PartydetailsApplication  : Starting PartydetailsApplication 
> > >       v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on partydetailswithdb-2-cs8jp with PID 1 (/partyv2.jar started 
> > >       by 1000880000 in /)
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:09.532  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.openbanking.PartydetailsApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:09.817  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@16b4a017: startup date [Fri Sep 06 05:19:09 GMT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:15.003  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'webServiceConfig' of type [com.cg.openbanking.configuration.WebServiceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1f075603] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:15.015  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5052733] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:15.143  INFO 1 --- [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
> > >       2019-09-06 05:19:15.237  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'io.opentracing.contrib.spring.cloud.async.DefaultAsyncAutoConfiguration$DefaultTracedAsyncConfigurerSupport' of type [io.opentracing.contrib.spring.cloud.async.DefaultAsyncAutoConfiguration$DefaultTracedAsyncConfigurerSupport$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$55d5a4ef] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:15.600  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$106d6234] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:16.139  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'io.opentracing.contrib.spring.cloud.async.DefaultAsyncAutoConfiguration' of type [io.opentracing.contrib.spring.cloud.async.DefaultAsyncAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$56f3758c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:18.896  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9999 (http)
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:19.108  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:19.109  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.35
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:19.202  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:19.501  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
> > >       2019-09-06 05:19:19.501  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 9692 ms
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:19.895  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.c.s.w.a.ServerTracingAutoConfiguration : Creating FilterRegistrationBean bean with TracingFilter mapped to [/*], skip pattern is "/api-docs.*|/autoconfig|/configprops|/dump|/health|/info|/metrics.*|/mappings|/swagger.*|.*.png|.*.css|.*.js|.*.html|/favicon.ico|/hystrix.stream"
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:20.131  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'tracingFilter' to urls: [/*]
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:20.132  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:20.132  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:20.132  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:20.132  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:20.132  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet messageDispatcherServlet mapped to [/ws/*]
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:20.133  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:21.301  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:22.303  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:22.825  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:22.933  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
> > >               name: default
> > >               ...]
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:23.230  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
> > >
> > > 2019-09-06 05:19:23.234  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found

Comment: what exactly is the error? you want us to try and read that unformatted (I presume) stacktrace and guess?

Comment: Not Exactly, But I want to know the error also. Whatever I have mentioned in the description, i got the same when i check the logs.

Comment: stack trace does not have any errors. Looks like an issue with server itself.

Comment: Run `oc get events`. See if it means anything about failure of health probes or killed because of excessive memory etc.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton No such things observed in events.

Last event I received is, Error creating deployer pod: pods "springbootmysql-1-deploy" already exists 

but I dont think this will be the issue.